# Conexion MySql servidor linux desde app en windows

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, mariadb

no sé si esta consulta este en el rango del objetivo de la página.

Alguno se ha topado con tener que conectar una aplicación desde visual studio a una **DB MySql** alojada en un servidor linux?

Intente conectarme con un **connection string** cambiando a los parametros del motor, pero no funciona.

Quizas tenga algo que ver, que el servidor no tiene interfaz grafica, ya que cuando ingreso por putty al servidor, primero inicio con root, luego si puedo acceder a la db.

Comment: Primero tendrías que comprobar que tienes la dll de EF para mysql instalada, luego verificar que el puerto de mysql esta abierto en el servidor y comprobar la configuración (user, password, ip y puerto) del connection string

Comment: Decir simplemente _no funciona_ no es de mucha ayuda. ¿Qué error específico tienes? ¿qué has intentado?. Por favor lee https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/21

Comment: @jachguate El error: **No tienes permiso sobre Maria Db**, lo curioso es que son las mismas credencias que uso en el putty

Comment: tienes que crear un usuario y contraseña dentro de mariadb y utilizar estos (asignandole permisos), no sirve usar el usuario root de linux

Comment: @osiris85 Si claro tienes razón, quizas no me explique bien, luego de acceder con root, con las credenciales de la db puedo ingresar; son esas mismas las que uso en mi cadena de conexión, no las del root

Comment: y el código que creaste donde esta?, en algo tienes razón la consulta no esta acorde a la política de stackoverflow @jachguate en el link que publico debes darle una ojeada leerlo, edita tu pregunta.

Comment: Supongo que estarás usando el conector de mysql y no un SqlConnection...Tambien ten en cuenta que hay configurar el mysql para que acepte conexiones remotas

Answer (score -1):

Es muy posible que sea un tema de permisos.Para poder tener acceso remoto a un servidor de base de datos MySql, debes ejecutar el siguiente comando como root:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' with grant option;
```

Si no quieres especificar una ip en concreto, sustituye `IP` por `%`.

Después de eso, debes reiniciar el servidor, o ejecutar `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Está explicado en varios sitios, por ejemplo aquí: [Configure mariadb for remote client access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)